# Recomendation on literature about how to struct code on classes, methods, functions and so on

Tags: oop, uml

Although I have ten years of programming experience, I feel that I am at an amateur level when deciding on how to struct my code.

I'll give some examples to give a better idea of what I'm talking about.

1 - Compiler

I am writing a compiler for hobby language of my own and I've decided to create a Logger class to handle error messages, warning messages and so on. Then I wasn't sure on how to implement. Should I write something like this

```cpp
Logger log;
log.error("error message");
log.warn("warn message");
```

Or should I write something like this?

```cpp
Logger log;
log.log(Logger::ERROR, "error message");
log.log(Logger::WARN, "warn message");
```

Or instead of a simple string should I create a LogMessage class?

```cpp
LogMessage msg;
Logger log;

msg.content("error message");
msg.severity(Logger::ERROR);
msg.file(current_file); // file that produced the log

log.log(msg);
```

In this particular case of logging, it seems that the official Java API regarding logging implements all these alternatives and some more.

2 - A simple TeX parser

Another project I am working needs to parse a small subset of TeX input. One of the steps of this projects needs to read an input like this:

```
\chapter{Foo} hello, world \section{Bar}
```

And split the input into an array of strings like this

```py
["\chapter{Foo}", " hello, world ", "\section{Bar}"]
```

I implemented this functionality using a simple function, but talking with a friend, he said that he probably would have created a specialized class to handle such split in order to follow the SOLID principle. In this case, he argued that the class would be small and have only a single concern as SOLID advocates and that classes are more versatile than functions.

3 - The compiler again

Almost everyone knows that a compiler is not a trivial project. But in my case, my most troublesome issues were regarding abstractions on how to communicate and pass data among the compilation steps. I've rewritten the compiler from scratch four times by now. Each rewrite I've improved the Lexer and Parser code, but I never passed from the semantic phase because I still haven't found a proper and efficient way to tie together the semantic steps, the parser, the lexer, user-defined types, and symbol tables. All my approaches seem to degenerate on a myriad of cases to handle one by one, the code becomes too much verbose and I get frustrated because in my mind I believe that there is a better and elegant way to code instead of handling case by case.

As an example, consider the following inputs to be processed by the compiler

```c
p->foo[2](2, 3)
p->bar = 2
p->baz[2][3].foobar->foo[2](2, 3)
```

Those simple inputs cause me nightmares because I must check, for example, if the left side of the -> operator, for instance, is a simple member, a function, an array and so on. And in order to produce error messages, I must coordinate symbol tables, the name of the file where the error is produced and so on. I get lost on how to pass so much information around without producing code that is too much verbose.

Before I came here to ask this question, I really thought about how to not let this question become opinionated, subjective and so on. So I decided to ask for books, articles and so on this subject. I would like recommendations of literature on how to struct a program. How to decide if a given functionality should be implemented as a class, or as a method, or as a function. On how to define abstractions to communicate among layers of the software stack. How to define an API and so on. Maybe some visual methodology to guide the structuring process. Ideally, an algorithm on how to code a complex and big algorithm.

Comment: Your question if off-topic in many ways. a) it's way too broad and b) you asking for recommendations. 10 years isn't much actually. Look at the Dunning-Kruger curve https://i.imgur.com/jbo2gy5.jpg and locate yourself.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand. Is it broad because I am asking for literature on this subject or because my examples are subjective? Please help me how I could improve my question

Comment: Please click the question mark icon top right and read how to ask a question here. Asking for recommendations is off-topic.